# One to one Bivariate Transformation

Tags: probability, transformation

Why does the below show the transformation is one to one?

[image]
These are lecture notes ( the text and the blue writing)

Comment: If you can find the inverse, then it's invertible.  If it's invertible, then the original is one-to-one.  Note that $X\to Z_1$ and $Y\to Z_2$ are not claimed invertible, just the combined $(X,Y)\to(Z_1,Z_2)$.

Comment: So the supports are unrelated to it being invertible?

Comment: Bounties are no substitute for explanations about what you fail to understand and what you tried to solve this question.